# NSString Memory Leak

Tags: objective-c, memory-leaks

```
- (NSString*) getProjectCoreName
{
    return [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@_%ld", kTLProject, sProjectCores++];
}
```

Instruments is telling me 32 bytes is leaking from the above function. The string is used as a key in a static NSMutableDictionary:

```
[dictionary setObject:instance forKey:name];
```

This dictionary is never released during the course of the program. Is this a leak? This is a MacOS application.

The dictionary is defined statically:

```
static NSMutableDictionary *dictionary = nil;
```

Then later:

```
if(dictionary == nil){
    dictionary = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithCapacity:5];
    [dictionary retain];
};
```

Comment: Firstly, be wary of running leaks on iOS 4.3 because it's reporting leaks within a number of provided objects. From what I've seen on here and forums, these are bugs either in leaks or in the newer versions.  Try running under iOS 4.2.  Secondly, can you specify when the memory is leaking (program start, program end, after some operation)?

Comment: How are you creating the dictionary?  If it's in the autorelease pool, then that shouldn't be the cause of your leak.

Comment: @Tahoe: Thanks, but this is not iOS.

Comment: @highlycaffeinated: The dictionary is in the autorelease pool. I have updated the question with the dictionary's initialization.

Comment: @Tahoe: The memory leak seems to be occuring when I destroy the object that the string is a key for. I call the [dictionary removeObjectForKey:name]; function and the object is correctly de-alloced, but the key is not.

Comment: What else do you do with the name?

Comment: I use the name to retrieve the object later, and then grab some properties off the object. When the 'leak' occurs both objects are dealloced correctly.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This function itself does not contain a memory leak. `stringWithFormat` returns an autoreleased object and so are you. If there is a leak it must be somewhere else.

Comment: Leaks has stopped reporting this as an error. I am going to assume it is something quirky with leaks and that I do not have a memory leak.

Comment: I'm happy your leak is gone. Anyway, bear in mind that Instruments only tells you where the leaked object was created. It can't tell you where you failed to release it (which is why the leak) because that could be anywhere. This is why Instruments was reporting that method.

Comment: please see my answer on this link . it may help you. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6185533/memory-leak-in-nsstring-stringwithutf8string/9955130#9955130